# HTML/CSS transparency through multiple layers

Tags: html, css, z-index, transparency

Is it possible to create an element, that creates a transparency through x-number of layers 'behind' it?

Example: I have layers with z-indexes 1,2,3,4, whereas 1 is red. I then create a '5th' layer, that I want to cut through the colors of layers 2,3,4 and see the red color through. Is that possible?

Comment: Interesting. Are the elements siblings or children?

Comment: You can play around with the `z index` of the underlying layers dynamically using jQuery

Answer (score 4):

You can experiment with the new `mix-blend-mode` and/or `background-blend-mode` (*if you have background images*) which is currently in candidate recommendation for [Compositing and blending Level 1](https://drafts.fxtf.org/compositing-1/#mix-blend-mode).

References: [blend modes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/blend-mode), and [mix-blend-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode).

Be advised though, that this is currently [not supported by IE, Edge and Opera](http://caniuse.com/#search=mixblendmode).

In the example below, you can see that the top-level `div` shows *red* seeping thru from the lowest-level `div`.

**Example Snippet**:

```css
.red { background-color: red; }
.blue { background-color: blue; }
.green { background-color: green; }
.yellow { background-color: yellow; }
div { 
    width: 120px; height: 120px;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 16px; left: 16px;
}
div:nth-of-type(2) { top: 32px; left: 32px; mix-blend-mode: difference; }
div:nth-of-type(3) { top: 48px; left: 48px; mix-blend-mode: overlay;}
div:nth-of-type(4) { top: 64px; left: 64px; mix-blend-mode: multiply; }
```

```html
<div class="red">1</div>
<div class="blue">2</div>
<div class="green">3</div>
<div class="yellow">4</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm gonna have to look a bit more into how it works. What exactly is multiplied? Any other color-combination doesn't give the desired result, but thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Jeppe: This ref will give you clarity on how different blend-modes work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/blend-mode. One needs to carefully craft them depending on what result one is after.

Comment: @Jeppe: However, I do feel that going with different images would better work for you. That would be much simpler. There is no other way.

Answer (score 2):

#### Transparensy trough multiple elements

Lets try it out:

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 50px solid transparent;
}
.a1 {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}
.a2 {
  background-color: rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.5);
}
.a3 {
  background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.5);
}
.a4 {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}
.a5 {
  background-color: rgba(238, 130, 238, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="a1">
  <div class="a2">
    <div class="a3">
      <div class="a4">
        <div class="a5">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Seems like there is transparency trough all elements.

Comment: Yeah, i know how opacity works. But the red color isnt shown through the 5th layer.. A combination of the opacities of the layers 1-4 is. I'm using colors as an example - it may as well be .png's or something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the color and transparency of that color in css,
If none of the opacity's combined is 100%, you should be able to get a mix of the colors.

That would look like:

```
.elclass{
   background-color:#f00;
   opacity:.2; //20% opacity;
}
```

if you don't want the opacity of the object to be 20%, but just the background-color use:

```
.elclass{
   background-color:rgba(255,0,0,.2);
}
```

rgba colors are however not 100% browser safe.